# .Net 4.5 Project with Reference to .Net 4.5 and netstandard2.0 Project pulls wrong version but works

Tags: c#, .net-standard-2.0

I have a class library that I've ported from `.Net 4.5` to a new multi-target class library targeting `.Net 4.5` and `netstandard2.0`.  This all seems to work as expected.

However, my unit test library in the same solution is targeting `.Net 4.5`.  When I look at the project reference, it seems to be pulling in the `netstandard2.0` binary.  When I run the unit tests, everything compiles and works as expected, however, it was my understanding that I'd need to be targeting at least `.Net 4.6.1` for the project to successfully use a `netstandard2.0` reference.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You don't actually have 4.5 installed on the machine.  Nobody does anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant Sure, that makes sense, and I’ve surely got a compatible framework on my machine, but what would happen if the tests were run on a machine with 4.5 only? Would it fail to bind in that scenario? I suppose my disconnect is in why the project chose to bind to my machine’s specs vs what some random machine could have. Any further insight would be appreciated. I’m just surprised it doesn’t go the “safe” route and choose the 4.5 binding.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from Microsoft Documentation Says

> The various .NET implementations target specific versions of .NET Standard. Each .NET implementation version advertises the highest .NET Standard version it supports, a statement that means it also supports previous versions. For example, the .NET Framework 4.6 implements .NET Standard 1.3, which means that it exposes all APIs defined in .NET Standard versions 1.0 through 1.3. Similarly, the .NET Framework 4.6.1 implements .NET Standard 1.4, while .NET Core 1.0 implements .NET Standard 1.6.

Hope it helps

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)